# Persist conda env created during docker image creation

Tags: docker, dockerfile, conda, vscode-remote

My Docker file in the *.devcontainer* folder in the root of my Python workspace looks like this

```docker
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/miniconda:0-3

RUN apt-get update
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends make
RUN apt-get -y install gcc git-lfs python3-dev build-essential

# Copy environment.yml (if found) to a temp location so we update the environment. Also
# copy "noop.txt" so the COPY instruction does not fail if no environment.yml exists.
COPY environment.yml* .devcontainer/noop.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/
RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then /opt/conda/bin/conda env update --name base --file /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; fi
RUN rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp
```

What I am hoping this would achieve is that

1. Conda itself would be updated and
2. The conda environment in my *environment.env* file would be created.

In fact neither of these happens.

When I let VSCode build the Docker image and reopen my workspace in the resulting container there is only one conda environment listed (*base*) and it has not been updated, i.e. I still have to run the commands

```bash
conda update --name base conda --channel anaconda
conda env create --file environment.yml
```

Why hasn't the conda stuff in my Dockerfile persisted into the container? Or is there something wrong with the stuff I am doing in the Dockerfile (there's no error I can see in the logs)?

Comment: Have you verified that if you comment out the `RUN rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp` the `environment.yml` file is copied and present in the resulting image?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any command for updating Conda in your Dockerfile. You will need to include the relevant command to update Conda itself.

```
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base conda --yes
```

And the command `/opt/conda/bin/conda env update --name base --file /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml` is aimed to update the base environment rather than creating a new one.
Instead of updating the base environment, if you aim to create a new environment from `environment.yml`, you would use:

```
RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; fi
```

If you still want to update the base environment, make sure your `environment.yml` file specifies the packages to install or update in the `base` environment.

Your Dockerfile would therefore be:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/miniconda:0-3

# Update apt-get and install packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends make gcc git-lfs python3-dev build-essential

# Update Conda
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base conda --yes

# Copy environment.yml to a temp location and update/create environment
COPY environment.yml* .devcontainer/noop.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/
RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; fi

# Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp
```

That should update Conda and then create a new Conda environment based on your `environment.yml` file (if it exists).